# Streamwriter Lock Not Working

Tags: c#, file, locking, streamwriter

I'm taking over a C# project, and when testing it out I'm getting errors.  The error is that the log file cannot be written to because it is in use by another process.  Here's the code:

```
    public void WriteToLog(string msg)
    {
        if (!_LogExists) 
        {
            this.VerifyOrCreateLogFile();  // Creates log file if it does not already exist.
        }

        // do the actual writing on its own thread so execution control can immediately return to the calling routine.
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(WriteToLog));
        t.Start((object)msg);
    }

    private void WriteToLog(object msg)
    {
        lock (_LogLock)
        {
            string message = msg as string;
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(LogFile))
            {
                sw.Write(message);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

_LogLock is defined as a class variable:

```
    private object _LogLock = 0;
```

Based on my research and the fact that this has been working fine in a production system for a few years now, I don't know what the problem could be.  The lock should prevent another thread from attempting to write to the log file.

The changes I've made that need to be tested are a lot more log usage.  We're basically adding a debug mode to save much more info to the log than used to be saved.

Thanks for any help!

*EDIT*:

Thanks for the quick answers!  The code for VerifyOrCreateLogFile() does use the _LogLock, so that shouldn't be an issue.  It does do some writing to the log before it errors out, so it gets past creating the file just fine.

What seems to be the problem is that previously only one class created an instance of the log class, and now I've added instances to other classes.  It makes sense that this would create problems.  Changing the _LogLock field to be static fixes the issue.

Thanks again!

Comment: is there only a singleton instance of the class those methods belong to? The reason I ask is because the lock will only protect two threads using the same instance. Two instances writing to the same file would happily step on each other.

Comment: @Greg: could you share code of the VerifyOrCreateLogFile() method, perhaps it forgot to release log file handle in some cases? I hope mentioned method uses _LogLock when accessing a file...

Comment: The exception could be happening in VerifyOrCreateLogFile() - is that protected too?

Comment: Because _LogLock is not static you need to ensure only one instance of the logging class can be instantiated at any time (Singleton pattern).

Comment: why don't you just use a logging framework?

Comment: Please post the exact error, copy/paste it. I assume it's "File cannot be _created_ because it's in use" and the entire problem is in code not posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The lock should prevent another thread from attempting to write to the log file.

This is only true if you're using a single instance of this class.

If each (or even some) of the log requests use a separate instance, then the lock will not protect you.

You can easily "correct" this by making the  `_LogLock` field `static`:

```
private static object _LogLock = 0;
```

This way, all instances will share the *same* lock.

Comment: Thanks, definitely helpful information.  I did add new instances of the log class, when before there was only one instance.  However, after making the _LogLock field static, I still get the same IOException regarding another process using the file.  Any other suggestions?  I appreciate it!

Comment: @Greg: Is somethign else using the file/writing to it/or reading from it?

Comment: thanks, I got it figured out and working.  The issue was I was setting a different field, LogLock, to be static.  Setting the correct field, _LogLock, to be static fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 problems with the code:

- Lock must be the same among all "users" of ths Log class, easiest solution is to make either `_LogLock` or the complete class `static`
- `VerifyOrCreateLogFile` could pose a problem if 2 or more parallel threads call `WriteToLog` when `_LogExists` is false...

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the OS isn't releasing the file lock quickly enough before you exit the `lock` in `WriteToLog` and another thread that was blocked waiting for the lock tried to open it before the OS finished releasing the file lock. Yes, it can happen. You either need to sleep for a little before trying to open the file, centralize the writing to the log to a dedicated object (so that he and only he has access to this file and you don't have to worry about file lock contentions).

Another possibility is that you need to lock around

```
if (!_LogExists)  {
    this.VerifyOrCreateLogFile();  // Creates log file if it does not already exist.
}
```

The third possibility  is that you have multiple instances of whatever class is housing these methods. The lock object won't be shared across instances (make it `static` to solve this).

At the end of the day, unless you're an expert in writing safe multi-threaded code, just let someone else worry about this stuff for you. Use a framework that handles these issues for you (log4net?).

Answer (score 0):

you can do the code executable by simply

removing  **sw.Close()**; from your code ...

do it....
it will work fine.....